# how to cache data repository in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just wonder how to cache my data repository I mean there are some data repositories in my project they are so useful and I have to call their method several times so I need some tools or maybe patterns to cache them on the client to avoid get extra and duplicate queries.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Dropdownlist1" runat="server" DataTextField="DataTextField" DataValueField="Key">
</asp:DropDownList>

Dropdownlist1.DataSource = dbContext.EntityTest1;
Dropdownlist1.DataBind();
```

For each running the page or web application whenever I use this control it makes an executable linq query and caching data from sql server then transfer them to client but in fact it is unnecessary.

I think there are two different caching server side between sql server and application to avoid extra fetching data. and second caching client side between my application and client.

What is the best solution for caching ? and is there any sample project to explain both of them ?

Comment: I've always liked Steve Smith's CachedRepository Pattern http://ardalis.com/introducing-the-cachedrepository-pattern He demonstrates using MVC, but the repository principles should be the same.